# Creating a string with value blank and set it on clipboard

Tags: c#, string

when I got a string of blank("") and I try to set it on clipboard on a button press , The program crash.

Let says

```
 this.button1.onclick+=new Eventhandler(clicked);
```

method

```
 void onclick(object sender,EventArge e)
      {
        clipboard.Settext(textbox1.Text); // textbox1.text is blank
      }
```

When I clicked the button, it crashes.

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: wudzik and Daniel is right

Comment: I never liked using the escape sequece char, if I want to insert a quote in a string I'd use: (char)34 along with String.Format, it's much "nicer", imo.

Comment: the downvotes are caused by http://www.google.com/search?q=c%23+double+quote+in+string

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to excape it with `\`

```
string example = "\"";
```

or with `@` (as Daniel suggested)

```
string example = @"""";
```

Comment: or use `@` and `""` as `@""""`.

Comment: Thanks , sorry for my dullness , I didn't do any research.

Comment: @DanielA.White I was writing seconds after :) thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape it like this:

```
var example = "\"";
```

Or use a verbatim string literal with a double `"`:

```
var example = @"""";
```

Comment: I'm so sorry Simon, I was try to edit my answer but I edit your's accidently. I screwed up your answer :(

Comment: No need to apologise :)

Comment: Random downvoter care to comment?

Answer (score 0):

`"` is an *escape sequence* character.

You need to escape it with `\` like;

```
string example = "\"";
```

From [`Escape Sequences`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h21280bw.aspx)

```
Escape Sequence -- Represents
\"              -- Double quotation mark
```

From [*Wikipedia*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_sequence#Programming_languages)

> In many programming languages escape sequences are used in character
>   literals and string literals, to express characters **which are not
>   printable or clash with the syntax of characters or strings**. The
>   escape character is usually the backslash. For example the single
>   quotation mark character might be expressed as `'\''` since writing
>   `'''` is not acceptable.

As an alternative, you can use your string as a *verbatim string literal*.

From [`2.4.4.5 String literals`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

> A verbatim string literal consists of an `@` character followed by a
>   double-quote character, zero or more characters, and a closing
>   double-quote character. A simple example is @"hello". In a verbatim
>   string literal, the characters between the delimiters are interpreted
>   verbatim, the only exception being a quote-escape-sequence.

```
string example = @""";
```